# Protected Constructor Derived Class Issue

Tags: c#, class, methods, constructor, protected

I'm sure this question has been asked quite a few times; however I'm running into a problem. So I've created a separate class; specifically to verify that the proper user level is present.

Below is the code to test those permission levels:

```
    class Elevated_Rights
    {

        // Token Bool:
        private bool _level = false;

        #region Constructor:

        protected Elevated_Rights()
        {

            // Invoke Method On Creation:
            Elevate();

        }

        #endregion

        public void Elevate()
        {

            // Get Identity:
            WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

            // Set Principal
            WindowsPrincipal role = new WindowsPrincipal(user);

            #region Test Operating System for UAC:

            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT || Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
            {

                // False:
                _level = false;

                // Todo: Exception/ Exception Log

            }

            #endregion

            else
            {

                #region Test Identity Not Null:

                if (user == null)
                {

                    // False:
                    _level = false;

                    // Todo: "Exception Log / Exception"

                }

                #endregion

                else
                {

                    #region Ensure Security Role:

                    if (!(role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)))
                    {

                        // False:
                        _level = false;

                        // Todo: "Exception Log / Exception"

                    }

                    else
                    {

                        // True:
                        _level = true;

                    }

                    #endregion


                } // Nested Else 'Close'

            } // Initial Else 'Close'

        } // End of Class.

    }
```

So that part is working as intended; however when I inherit this class into another class to utilize the protected constructor is where I hit a snag.

```
    class Default_Configuration : Elevated_Rights
    {

        #region Constructor:

        public Default_Configuration() : base()
        {


            Elevate();


        }

        #endregion



    }
```

But When I call that new class; the method states: "Invalid Access due to Constructor Permission". It theoretically should work; is there something I'm missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The method states...."?  This sounds like a runtime, not compiler issue...  Are you using Lazy<T> or anything like that which constructs instances at runtime?

Comment: You do realize you're going to be calling `Elevate()` twice, as currently written?

Comment: can you post the invoking code ?

Comment: While I don't recognize that error, classes (except nested classes) are `internal` by default, so unless you're using that class within the same assembly a public constructor is pointless.

Comment: Also please double-check your error message, the phrase "Invalid Access due to Constructor Permission" appears nowhere in google apart from this question, so I suspect you didn't copy & paste it accurately.

Comment: Thanks Bobson; didn't even realize that.

Comment: The code above does work; it works as intended.  I just made a stupid error that I overlooked.  Which once I simplified; I removed the error.  Thanks for all the help though I read that blog post.  Good read; thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lies elsewhere: I pasted those two class definitions into a project, builds just fine. Instantiated a new `Default_Configuration`, called `Elevate()`, no errors.

If you have other issues with mixing `public` and `protected` methods, here's a [blog post by Peter Hallam](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peterhal/archive/2005/06/29/434070.aspx) that describes the issues.

Basically, you can't call a `protected` instance method in a base class from a `public` instance method in a derived class; doing so would allow a "malicious" derived class from making all the `protected` methods in the base class `public`, just by writing wrappers for them.

Comment: Does that apply to constructors, too?  I'd assume that a public constructor could call a base protected one.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be curious as well. Thanks for the post.

Comment: @Bobson: the public constructor calling the base protected constructors worked fine for me when I copied in the code from this question.

Comment: Good to know - I figured it would work, but it's always good to have it confirmed.

Comment: Yeah, my issue was some where else in the application.  But thank you all for the feedback. Helped me ensure my sanity wasn't lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
        new Default_Configuration().Elevate();
```

this line works for me.

What is not working for you?